# GarageBand not starting after Snow Leopard upgrade

Tags: snow-leopard, garageband

Starting four days ago, I wasn't able to open any of the icons at the bottom of the page of my MacBook. I downloaded Snow Leopard, and now I can open all but GarageBand. This is a complete mystery to me.

I'm currently at OS X 10.6.3. (my Mac was bought used, do I need something newer to run Garageband?. How can I get GarageBand to run again?

Answer (score 1):

You need a GarageBand version 6.05 from [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1507).

And you need to update your Snow Leopard to [10.6.8](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1400)